# Run dataset through a series of functions

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I am using the R-Studio IDE on a Windows 7, 64 machine.  How can I run a dataset through a series of functions and print the result?

My dataset is in a .csv format which I have already imported into R. It is a header with descriptive titles (A1, B1, C1, etc).  The first column corresponds to my sample name (Sample1, Sample2, etc).  So each row is the data for a single sample.

```
attach(dataset)
K <- function(W4060, W4672, W4332, W4484) {
    ((W4060*W4672/W4332/W4484)-0.103)*7.3+5.8
    return()
    }
N <- function(W4032, W4000, W4720, W4060, W4040) {
    ((W4032+W4000+W4720)/(W4060+W4040)-0.637)*171+50
    return()
    }
```

I used the attach function to incorporate the dataset.  However, I have no idea how to print each value for each sample on to a single data frame. 
Any help or step in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is really intended for when you've reached the phase where you know enough to at least make an attempt. Otherwise, we're not really helping, we're doing other people's work for them, which isn't nearly as fun.

Comment: I agree with @joran - but, for my own fun, was just about to post these attempts: `mydata <- data.frame(A1=rnorm(10),B1=rnorm(10),C1=rnorm(10)); myfunc <- function(A1,B1,C1) A1+B1*C1; apply(mydata,1,function(x) do.call(myfunc,as.list(x))); do.call(mapply,c(list(FUN=myfunc),mydata)); with(mydata,eval(body(myfunc)))` ... :)

Comment: Question has modified.  Thanks

Comment: I have figured this out.  The problem i had was not naming the list for the calculated data, so nothing ever stored.